# Ionic Framework installed but not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, ionic-framework, installation, ubuntu-16.04

when i try to check the version of my installed ionic dependence or start a new blank project it gives errors.

Please help me this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MafIU.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be having a problem in Node.js

re-install Node.js and make sure you have the latest version of Node.js and npm. Try this link:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js

then reinstall ionic and cordova.

For Installing Ionic, Bower, Gulp & Cordova , use

```
$npm install -g ionic bower gulp gulp-util cordova
```

After this, create an ionic project called myApp(say):

```
$ionic start myApp blank
```

change directory:

```
$cd myApp
```

check platforms available using:

```
$ionic platform
```

build a platform and run it(change ios to android if required):

```
$ionic platform add ios
$ionic build ios
$ionic emulate ios
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your Help. Let me Try this.

Comment: still facing the same Problem.

Comment: Try `npm clean cache` then install ionic again.